# @font-face Not Loading In Any Browser

Tags: html, css, web, font-face

I am a rookie to @font-face. I've gone through all of the posts here, several tutorials and I can't figure out why my fonts aren't loading. I'm activating and deactivating the font to see if it loads via the server with no luck. Weird thing is when it's activated, it works in the browser but not locally.

I have the css file in the fonts folder and all uploaded to the server. I've tested the demo file that came with the font and that works fine.

I'm sure I'm missing something very basic and I'll feel very stupid.

Here is my @font-face css:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'capsuularegular';
    src: url('fonts/Capsuula-webfont.eot');
    src: url('fonts/Capsuula-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('fonts/Capsuula-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('fonts/Capsuula-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('fonts/Capsuula-webfont.svg#capsuularegular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
```

And here is the page I'm trying to get it to work on:
http://takatech.com/index.2.html#

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: do website is deployed on iis???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because the font-family is `capsuularegular` and you have in your #main-wide `Capsuula`

So, change your CSS to this:

```
#main-wide {
    color: #999999;
    font-family: "capsuularegular";
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 30px;
    text-align: left;
}
```

Comment: I think that did it!! I don't have the font activated on my computer and it seems to be working. Refresh and you should see the font in the nav menu and body text change (I'm giong to change the body text font). You're a genius! Thanks!

Comment: This actually helped me too, I had blindness to the fact that my font was called "CSS Sans" instead of the font belonging to a large corp that I was working for. D'OH!

Answer (score 1):

Your fonts are located in `http://takatech.com/fonts/` but external stylesheets reference directories according to where the stylesheet is. So by specifying `fonts/Capsuula-webfont.eot` it will look for that font in `http://takatech.com/fonts/fonts/Capsuula-webfont.eot`

Try this instead:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'capsuularegular';
    src: url('/fonts/Capsuula-webfont.eot');
    src: url('/fonts/Capsuula-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('/fonts/Capsuula-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('/fonts/Capsuula-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('/fonts/Capsuula-webfont.svg#capsuularegular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
```

Comment: Thanks Josh. Gave that a try. No dice. Also tried it with "../"

Comment: @user2744584 The issue still seems to be that the fonts are not downloading, so they're probably not referenced properly. I checked using Chrome dev tools.

Comment: Yep. Had the font name wrong. Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the web.config to allow custom fonts download to client. Example:

```
<system.webServer>
  ...
  <staticContent>
    <remove fileExtension=".woff" />
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/font-woff" />
  </staticContent>
</system.webServer>
```